# Basic properties of free product amalgamation of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, free-product

I have some basic questions about properties of free product amalgamation of groups. Both can be phrased inside some fixed group $G$, which I am thinking of as having some very large infinite cardinality (but I don't think this is important).

Given subgroups $A,B\leq G$, I will use $\langle AB\rangle$ to denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by $A\cup B$ (equivalently, by the set product $AB$).

Given subgroups $A,B,C\leq G$, with $C\leq A\cap B$, I will use $A\ast_C B$ to denote the usual free product amalgamation of $A$ and $B$ over $C$ (as in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product#Generalization:_Free_product_with_amalgamation)).

Edit (re: Derek Holt's very good suggestion)
Given subgroups $A,B,C\leq G$, I will write $\langle ABC\rangle\cong\langle AC\rangle\ast_C\langle BC\rangle$ to mean that the identity map on $A\cup B\cup C$ generates an isomorphism between the two groups.

**Question #1**

Fix subgroups $D\leq C\leq B\leq G$ and $A\leq G$. Consider the following statements.

1) $\langle AB\rangle \cong \langle AC\rangle \ast_C B$ and $\langle AC\rangle\cong\langle AD\rangle\ast_D C$

2) $\langle AB\rangle \cong \langle AD\rangle\ast_D B$

What is the relationship between (1) and (2)? Are they equivalent?

**Question #2**

Fix subgroups $A,A',B,C\leq G$, with $C\leq A\cap A'\cap B$. Assume:

- $\langle AB\rangle\cong A\ast_C B$,
- $\langle A'B\rangle\cong A'\ast_C B$, and
- there is an isomorphism $\phi:A\longrightarrow A'$ such that $\phi(c)=c$ for all $c\in C$.

Define $\psi:\langle AB\rangle\longrightarrow\langle A'B\rangle$ such that $\psi$ extends $\phi$ and $\psi(b)=b$ for all $b\in B$. Is $\psi$ a well-defined isomorphism?

I imagine that these problems are not difficult for someone used to this kind of thing; so helpful answers would also include references to sufficiently similar exercises in standard texts.

Comment: I think the answer to both questions is yes provided that you assume that the isomorphisms are the natural ones. For example, in Question 2, you might consider assuming that the isomorphism $A*_C B \to \langle AB \rangle$ is induced by the identity maps on $A$ and $C$. Without that assumption I would be less confident, because the isomorphisms could conceivably be something completely unrelated!